# Linear operator T on space with inner product on C

Tags: functional-analysis

I have linear operator $T\rightarrow X:X$ , X is space with inner product on $\mathbb{C}.$
Is my train of thoughts correct?
$2 (\langle Tx,iy \rangle + \langle Tiy,x \rangle) = 2(-i \langle Tx,y \rangle + i \langle Ty,x \rangle) = 2i(\langle Ty,x \rangle - \langle Tx,y \rangle)$
If yes can somebody please explain what property do we use to get this
$\langle Tiy,x \rangle =i \langle Ty,x \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is linear an the inner product is linear in the first argument, you get

$\langle Tiy,x \rangle =i \langle Ty,x \rangle$.